# Commas in a hyphenated series

Tags: commas, hyphenation

I would like to make a statement to the effect of:

The coating contains durable wind-, rain-, and chemical-resistant compounds.

Can someone please provide guidance on the proper use of commas in this sentence.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a tricky one. My first instinct would be to re-write it in a way that avoided the dilemma (e.g. "..compounds that are resistant to wind, rain, and chemicals"). I'm curious to see the answers to this.

Comment: It seems to me you have got it exactly right already, Paul.

Answer (score -1):

I'd omit the commas after "wind" and "rain". Whether it is correct or not depends on the expert asked, it seems.

Comment: On what basis would you delete the comma after wind-? Some people who do not use the serial or Oxford comma might advise deleting the comma after rain-, but I cannot think of a reason to delete it after wind-. Please expound.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have said "hyphens" instead of "commas".